# Docker Passenger Dashboard shows MySQL can't connect to socket

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, passenger

I'm Trying to deploy Ruby on Rails app on phusion/passenger-ruby21 container and a separate mysql:5.5.46 container. Both are linked without docker compose.

I ran Passenger-ruby container with:
`sudo docker run -it -p 80:80 --link mysql55:mysql -e .env --name ror1 rubyonrails-phusionimg2 /bin/bash`

mysql container with:
`sudo docker run --detach --name mysql55 --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=**** --env MYSQL_USER=**** --env MYSQL_PASSWORD=****  --env MYSQL_DATABASE=**** mysql:5.5.46`

this is my `database.yml` in the Rails app.

```
staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: "<%= ENV["DATABASE_NAME"] %>"
  host: "<%= ENV["MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR"] %>"
  port: "<%= ENV["MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT"] %>"
  username: "<%= ENV["DATABASE_USERNAME"] %>"
  password: "<%= ENV["DATABASE_STAGING_PASSWORD"] %>"
```

Here is webapp.conf:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf:
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *****.com;
    root /home/app/webapp/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env staging;
    index index.html index.htm;
    # auth_basic "Restricted";
    # auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
}
```

`rake db:create db:migrate` runs successfully, which means that the rake program with staging environments is able to reach the mysql database container. But from the passenger dashboard I'm still getting the `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2)`

Am i missing something? All env's seem to be loaded and correct.

Comment: Attach additional info how you run your apps in docker, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed mysql database env variables in apps database.yml file which are preloaded when container is started and connected to mysql database. For example "DATABASE_NAME" to "MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE".

```
staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: <%= ENV['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD'] %>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify host of connection to mysql in your application.

If you don't specify host mysql will try to connect the server on you host not the one in the container.

Comment: MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR is the env varibale which contains IPaddress of the mysql container. I even  loaded the container name and tried , but no luck.